# Write to a dataframe or excel/csv file without overlapping in loop

Tags: python, excel, csv

Basically my algorithm creates rows such as:

```
[1 rows x 84 columns]
Date  1990-12-31  1991-09-30  1991-12-31  1992-03-31  1992-06-30  ...  2017-06-30  2018-12-31  2019-09-30  2019-12-31  2020-03-31
AEP         28.0      30.625       34.25       30.75      31.875  ...   69.470001   74.739998   93.690002   94.510002   79.980003        

[1 rows x 84 columns]
Date  1990-12-31  1991-09-30  1991-12-31  1992-03-31  1992-06-30  ...  2017-06-30  2018-12-31  2019-09-30  2019-12-31  2020-03-31        
HON     6.435244    8.639912   10.457272    12.03629   12.810903  ...  127.751709  132.119995  169.199997       177.0  133.789993        

[1 rows x 84 columns]
Date  1990-12-31  1991-09-30  1991-12-31  1992-03-31  1992-06-30  ...  2017-06-30  2018-12-31  2019-09-30  2019-12-31  2020-03-31        
BMY    15.942265   19.689886   20.998581    18.14325   15.674578  ...   55.720001       51.98   50.709999   64.190002   55.740002
```

My issue is to append these rows together in one `df` or `excel` file.

The function that creates these rows is called by a loop that has a list of the tickers. The **problem** is everytime I try to append or write something to a file it overwrites each previous ticker so in the end I end up with just variations of the BMY ticker.

This is the loop code, the function  is "ticker"

```
list=["CAT","CVX","BA","AEP","HON","BMY"]
for i in list:
    ticker(i)
```

```
def ticker(tick):
df = pd.read_csv (r"C:/Users/NAME/Desktop/S&P data/Data Compilation.csv")
df1=df.set_index(["Company Ticker"])
abt=pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/NAME/Desktop/S&P data/"+tick+"/"+tick+".csv")                                                 
abt1=abt[['Close',"Date"]]
# I tried a lot of methods to join, I manually inputted the dates I need.
# The code then appends the ticker data Close & price into a new sheet in Data Compilation
output=abt1.join(df1,how='left')
output=output[output["Date"].isin(['2020-03-31','2019-12-31','2019-09-30'   ,'2019-06-30'   ,'2019-03-31'   ,'2018-12-31'   ,'2018-09-30'   ,'2018-06-30'   ,'2018-03-31'   ,'2017-12-31'   ,'2017-09-30'   ,'2017-06-30'   ,'2017-03-31'   ,'2016-12-31'   ,'2016-09-30'   ,'2016-06-30'   ,'2016-03-31'   ,'2015-12-31'   ,'2015-09-30'   ,'2015-06-30'   ,'2015-03-31'   ,'2014-12-31'   ,'2014-09-30'   ,'2014-06-30'   ,'2014-03-31'   ,'2013-12-31'   ,'2013-09-30'   ,'2013-06-30'   ,'2013-03-31'   ,'2012-12-31'   ,'2012-09-30'   ,'2012-06-30'   ,'2012-03-31'   ,'2011-12-31'   ,'2011-09-30'   ,'2011-06-30'   ,'2011-03-31'   ,'2010-12-31'   ,'2010-09-30'   ,'2010-06-30'   ,'2010-03-31'   ,'2009-12-31'   ,'2009-09-30'   ,'2009-06-30'   ,'2009-03-31'   ,'2008-12-31'   ,'2008-09-30'   ,'2008-06-30'   ,'2008-03-31'   ,'2007-12-31'   ,'2007-09-30'   ,'2007-06-30'   ,'2007-03-31'   ,'2006-12-31'   ,'2006-09-30'   ,'2006-06-30'   ,'2006-03-31'   ,'2005-12-31'   ,'2005-09-30'   ,'2005-06-30'   ,'2005-03-31'   ,'2004-12-31'   ,'2004-09-30'   ,'2004-06-30'   ,'2004-03-31'   ,'2003-12-31'   ,'2003-09-30'   ,'2003-06-30'   ,'2003-03-31'   ,'2002-12-31'   ,'2002-09-30'   ,'2002-06-30'   ,'2002-03-31'   ,'2001-12-31'   ,'2001-09-30'   ,'2001-06-30'   ,'2001-03-31'   ,'2000-12-31'   ,'2000-09-30'   ,'2000-06-30'   ,'2000-03-31'   ,'1999-12-31'   ,'1999-09-30'   ,'1999-06-30'   ,'1999-03-31'   ,'1998-12-31'   ,'1998-09-30'   ,'1998-06-30'   ,'1998-03-31'   ,'1997-12-31'   ,'1997-09-30'   ,'1997-06-30'   ,'1997-03-31'   ,'1996-12-31'   ,'1996-09-30'   ,'1996-06-30'   ,'1996-03-31'   ,'1995-12-31'   ,'1995-09-30'   ,'1995-06-30'   ,'1995-03-31'   ,'1994-12-31'   ,'1994-09-30'   ,'1994-06-30'   ,'1994-03-31'   ,'1993-12-31'   ,'1993-09-30'   ,'1993-06-30'   ,'1993-03-31'   ,'1992-12-31'   ,'1992-09-30'   ,'1992-06-30'   ,'1992-03-31'   ,'1991-12-31'   ,'1991-09-30'   ,'1991-06-30'   ,'1991-03-31'   ,'1990-12-31'   ,'1990-09-30'   ,'1990-06-30'   ,'1990-03-31'])]
output=output.pivot_table(values='Close',columns='Date',aggfunc='first')
output=output.rename(index={"Close":tick})
print(output)
return output
```

Comment: if it is possible can you please share ticker function?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: thanks, I answered the question on assuming that you want to merge all rows in a dataframe but if you want the result in another form please give example about how you want your result to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge rows in one dataframe with same columns, below code may do the work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
list=["CAT","CVX","BA","AEP","HON","BMY"]
for i in list:
    responseDf = ticker(i)
    df = df.append(responseDf)
print(df)
```

"df" is your main dataframe and in each loop result dataframe from ticker function is added to the main dataframe by the "append" function.

Comment: I got an empty dataframe doing this. Maybe because theres more then one result from the function?

Comment: please set df value again on the append process, the first post was returning empty dataframe, sorry for that. I've edited the post.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much boss I really appreciate it. The easiest solution too, I should've known!

Comment: I am glad we solved it, I would appreciate it if you accept this as an answer.